# Obtain an Alien Registration Card (in Korea), in order to obtain a Russian visa

Tags: visas, russia, south-korea

I (German passport holder) can only apply for a Russian visa in my home country or the place of my current residence. Of course, I am already traveling. Soon I will go to Korea, where I have to keep my passport at all times. So I can't send it home for visa applications. It is possible for me, as a tourist, to obtain an Alien Registration Card (ARC) in Korea? With this card I could apply for a Russian via.

Comment: Presumably the answer to this question depends on the purpose and duration of your stay in Korea.  What are they?

Comment: Edited my question. I would be a regular tourist.

Comment: Does Germany allow for two passports? As a French citizen, I carry two French passports, and use one to apply for visas while I carry the other one.

Comment: FWIW, most officials will understand the situation and accept a color photocopy of your passport and a receipt for your visa application as a temporary substitute for ID purposes.

Comment: Indeed, two passports are allowed. Sadly I did not think about having two, when I started my journey. Obtaining a second one on the road seems to be nightmare. Sending my passport two Germany would be okay, but then I don't get any document/recipe for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a tourist you cannot obtain an ARC, because it is for residents, not tourists. Since you don't reside in Korea, you can't go to the Immigration office in Mok-dong and ask for a resident card. You'd need to enrol in a language course, for instance, or find a job.

Note that if for instance you enrolled in a language class, say a 6-month course while in Korea, you'd have to take a few points in consideration:

- Start date of the class: it's not a buffet. You can't start when you want.
- If you find a class while already in Korea, you'll have to leave Korea to invalide your tourist visa, go to a Korean consulate to apply for the student visa, and come back.
- You then need to go to Mok-dong and register. For first-timers, getting the card can take a few weeks (and a couple of visits to Mok-dong).